# Creating img database with arcoreimg tool

Tags: android, database, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I'm having issues to create an image database (.imgdb) for my arcore project. I've downloaded  arcore sdk for android and inside the folder tools there's arcoreimg for mac. When i try to follow the steps in here:

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/arcoreimg

the following is not working:

```
./arcoreimg build-db --input_image_list_path=/path/to/image_list_file.txt \
                   --output_db_path=/path/to/myimages.imgdb
```

(changing the path to my images obviously)

It says arcoreimg command not found when i execute it in the Terminal. What should i do? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using windows, so maybe stupid question, but are you in folder with arcoreimg in terminal when using this command?

Comment: Yes, i'm in macOS folder, where arcoreimg is. That's the reason why I do not get why the command is not found.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem, making the file executable fixed the problem for me:

`sudo chmod +x arcoreimg`

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation doesn't point to the right steps.

First, locate the `arcoreimg` file on your system. On MacOS, I found it inside `<arcore-sdk-location</arcore-android-sdk/tools/arcoreimg/macos`.

You can use the executable directly from here, or copy it to a more convenient location (maybe next to your images).

I copied it next to my images, opened the terminal in the folder, and then used the `eval-img` command, but the build db command should work the same way-

`./arcoreimg eval-img --input_image_path=dog.jpg`

This might give `permission denied` or `command not found`.

`sudo chmod +x arcoreimg` should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Give read/write access to your tool. Open your arcoreimg directory from terminal. And give following command

```
sudo chmod +x arcoreimg
```

**Step 2:** Copy your images in one folder

**Step 3:** Create one empty output folder

**Step 4:** Give following command

```
./arcoreimg build-db --input_images_directory="yourInputDirectoryPath"  --output_db_path="yourOutputDirectoryPath/databaseName.imgdb"
```

Sample command

```
./arcoreimg build-db --input_images_directory=/Users/ranjithkumar/Desktop/input_images  --output_db_path=/Users/ranjithkumar/Desktop/output_db/myImages.imgdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the official documentation on using this may not be very clear, as this portion `./arcoreimg` of the sample code refers to the exact directory where your arcoreimage cli tool is located, as well as the name it is called. So you may correctly run the code like this;

`/Users/.../GoogleARCore/CLI/augmented_image_cli_osx build-db --input_image_list_path=/path/to/image_list_file.txt \
                   --output_db_path=/path/to/myimages.imgdb`